# Add arguments in CMS Block

Tags: static-block, cms-block, bluefootcms

The project is using the Bluefoot plugin to add the block in cms_index_home. I created a static block in Magento Admin with the follow content:

```
{{block class="ProductsRegulars\Block\Recommendation\Lists" name="product-recommendation" template="recommendation/list.phtml}}
```

But in my cms_index_home.xml I have some arguments essentials to block.

```
<arguments>
    <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="recommendation-list" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">ProductsRegulars/js/view/recommendation/list</item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ProductsRegulars/recommendation/list</item>
                </item>

                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="messages" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">0</item>
                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/view/messages</item>
                        <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">messages</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</arguments>
```

**When I run the page, occur the following error:**

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
```

I believe that this error occurs because of the Magento not found the arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add your referenceBlock and write it's name . I hope it's work for you

```
<referenceBlock name="xxx.xxx.xxx">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="recommendation-list" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">ProductsRegulars/js/view/recommendation/list</item>
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ProductsRegulars/recommendation/list</item>
                    </item>

                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="messages" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">0</item>
                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/view/messages</item>
                            <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">messages</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>    
</referenceBlock>
```

Comment: I'll try that! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I added the **referenceBlock** in my **cms_index_home.xml**. I did the test with **identifier value** and **block name** but it still did not work.

**Static Block**
[image]

**cms_index_home.xml**

```
<referenceBlock name="product-recommendation">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="recommendation-list" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">ProductsRegulars/js/view/recommendation/list</item>
                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ProductsRegulars/recommendation/list</item>
                        </item>

                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="messages" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">0</item>
                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/view/messages</item>
                                <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">messages</item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
```